# Is this your friend? Isn't it or Isn't he?

Tags: pronouns, questions

I look at a picture of my friend and seeing another guy next to him. Then should I ask :

- Is this your friend? isn't it.

or

- Is this your friend? isn't he.

Please help me to correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this your friend?

This sentence is a question: it's fine on its own.  You don't need to add **isn't it?** or **isn't he?** because it is already a question.

You would use  **isn't it?** or **isn't he?** to ask confirmation of a statement (something that's not a question), for example:

> This is your friend, isn't it?
>   He is your friend, isn't he?

You use **isn't it** when **this** is the subject of the sentence, and **isn't he** when **he** is the subject of the sentence.